# Firebase fetching data works with simulator but not in app

Tags: security, dart, firebase

I've a problem with Firebase security rules. I'm storing data in the following way:

```
firebase_url
    appname
        datapath
            uid
                data1
                data2
                data3
                ...
```

And the security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "appname": {
      "datapath": {
        "$uid": { 
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
}}}}}
```

When I login with a user I always get permission denied to the specific path. For example:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for "FIREBASE_URL/appname/datapath/15" failed: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. 
Exception: Uncaught Error: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

15 is the user id for which I try to fetch the data. 
Using the simulator works flawlessly with the above url and with the user logged in but not from my web app which uses Firebase-Dart. Setting .read and .write simply to true "solves" the problem. I'm trying to read all the data from that url.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking that login actually succeeds?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, I can see the token and everything. The problem is "solved" anyway. It works now flawlessly for whatever reason. I did not alter any code.